# Avoid session cookies in Asp.NET Core 2.2 + IdentityServer

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I've been playing with Asp.NET Core 2.2 and Identity, using examples explained [here](https://damienbod.com/2018/04/15/supporting-both-local-and-windows-authentication-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-identityserver4/). In particular I'm using the StsServer app which allows a user to authenticate using OpenID Hybrid flow or Windows authentication.

What I have seen is that it stores: [image: chrome]

- 3 session cookies if user identity is not remembered
- 2 session cookies + 1 cookie if the user identity is remembered when the browser is reopened

Is there a way to avoid such cookies?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

The `.AspNetCore.AntiForgergy` cookie is not a session cookie. It's for CSRF. The `.AspNetCore.Identity` cookie is also not a session cookie. It's the auth cookie that persists the user's authenticated state when using Identity and Identity Server backed by ASP.NET Core Identity. Finally, the `idsrv.session` cookie is from Identity Server, and is used for OIDC session management, which is not a "session" in the sense you're probably thinking of. It's there to support maintaining the authenticated state, as well.

Long and short, they each have a specific purpose and you need all of them.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any other approaches to avoid cookies at all? I mean alternatives to Identity Server, still using ASP.NET core .

Comment: Why you say .AspNetCore.Identity is not a session cookie? If I not tick the Remember me on this pc tick box, it doesn't have an expiry date so I was assuming it could be called session cookie

Comment: Cookies cannot be avoided with anything but a static content website. HTTP is a stateless protocol. Cookies are what enable stateful interactions. If you need to maintain state at all, cookies will be involved. There's no way around that.

Comment: I've bumped into an issue when HTTP request header is too large. However I took a look at it - the cookies there are solely Identity Server cookies related to our several apps. I cannot affect these cookies - so how can I reduce total cookies size and eliminate the problem?